# How can I return the input of the API request into my html template, without it returning on my terminal using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

this is my function that uses google finance api to get news articles.

```
someapp/views.py

def news(request): 
        if request.method == 'POST':
            url = "https://google-finance4.p.rapidapi.com/ticker/"
    
            querystring = {"t":"ETH-USD","hl":"en","gl":"US"}
    
            headers = {
                "X-RapidAPI-Key": "API KEY",
                "X-RapidAPI-Host": "google-finance4.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
    
            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
            response.status_code
            response.text
            response.json()
            articles = response.json()['news']
            
    
           
    
            return render(request, 'news.html', {
                 "article": articles })  
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Error')
```

this is the html code

```
<body class="bg-dark">
    <div
      style="
        position: flex;
        width: 450px;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 370px auto;
      "
    >
      <img class ="img-fluid" src="{% load static %} /static/logo.png" "
      alt="Crypto Talk"
    </div>
    <p>**{{ article }}**</p>
  </body>
```

this is the html to the page where the POST request is coming from.

```
  <form
    class="form-inline"
    method="POST"
    action="{{ 'news/' }}"
    name="news"
  >
    <div
      class="input-group mb-3"
      style="margin: 0 auto; display: flex; width: 450px"
    >
      {%csrf_token%}
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Crypto"
        name="search"
        style="
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
          border-top-left-radius: 0;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
          border-top-left-radius: 5px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        "
      />
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md"
        type="submit"
        id="button-addon2"
      >
        Search
      </button>
```

for some reason it takes me to the new html but the page only has the logo. The content from the api I am looking to return is showing up in my terminal with the error "Not Found: /news/requestProvider.js.map"? is there something wrong with how im using Django's templating language or does it have to do with my views? Ultimately I am trying to render the articles found in the 'news' key when using this api and rendering it just like a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to change the text color! hahaha.